# Any way to view currently active trades with other civilizations?

Tags: civilization-6

I don't mean trade routes, but civ to civ trades with things like luxuries and gold. The only thing I can find is that you can get a little bit of info by hovering over your gold and see what is coming from trade deals that way - but I see no way of finding out what trade deals you have going on with other things like open borders, luxuries, etc. Is there no way of keeping track of that stuff?

This would really help to determine what luxuries you could trade for in order to increase amenities since having duplicates does nothing.

Comment: This is particularly an issue for luxury resources, it is pretty ridiculous that they do not even show up on the screen where it shows you your luxury resources. Another funny thing is the game doesn't even tell you what a bonus or luxury resource is from the report screen it mixes them together and omits resources you get from trades... please someone provide a mod to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.0.0.26 there is no way to see this information.

There is a mod called "Unit Report Screen" and as of version 1.51 you can see active trade deals from the report screen with it.

Here is a link
http://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/unit-report-screen.25396/